Nerve theorem for small permutative categories
For small categories, there is a famous Nerve theorem:
A simplicial set $X:\Delta^{op}\to Set$ is a nerve of a small category if and only if it satisfies the Segal conditions.
For small permutative categories, which are small symmetric strict monoidal categories, is there a similar Nerve theorem as follows?
A $\Gamma$-set $X:\Gamma^{op}\to Set$ is a nerve of a small permutative category if and only if it satisfies the Segal conditions, where $\Gamma$ is the Segal's category, the skeleton of the category $FinSet_∗ $ of pointed finite sets.
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/permutative+category
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144328/where-does-segals-category-come-from

I'm sorry, I deleted my previous answer because there is something that I didn't think about last night. I'll try to write a new answer today or tomorrow.

Thanks very much.
@Daniël Apol

This is not true. Given a symmetric strict monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, its nerve is not a $\Gamma$-set in a way that comes from the $\Delta$-set structure on it, because if such an extension was possible, then the flipping map $\mathrm{flip}\colon N\mathcal{C}_2\to N\mathcal{C}_2$ would respect composition: we would have $gf=fg$ for any pair of composable morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$. Even worse, we would ask for $gf=fg$ even if we only knew the target of $f$ is the source of $g$, so we would be in particular be asking that any morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ is an endomorphism.
Conversely, given a $\Gamma$-set $X$, we first look at the case where $X_0\cong *$. Then $X$ encodes a commutative monoid, in which $X_1$ is the set of elements, and the Segal conditions encode implicitly (among other things) the multiplication operation. Given a general $\Gamma$-set $X$, we can write $X_1\cong\bigsqcup_{p\in X_0} X_{1,p}$, and then the Segal condition $X_2\xrightarrow{\cong}X_1\times_{X_0}X_1$ tells us that we have a commutative monoid structure on each set $X_{1,p}$, but we have no operation relating an element of $X_{1,p}$ with an element of $X_{1,q}$ if $p\neq q$. So, in general, a $\Gamma$-set is just a (disjoint) collection of commutative monoids. This is not the same concept as a strict symmetric monoidal category.
Rather, if we look at $\Gamma$-categories, i.e. functors $X\colon\Gamma^\mathrm{op}\to\mathsf{Cat}$ to the $1$-category of (small) categories, then in case $X_0\cong *$ we do obtain a strict symmetric monoidal category. It is crucial to use the $1$-category of categories here, and not e.g. the $(2,1)$-category of those things, as that would encode just a symmetric monoidal category. Also note that the nerve of a strict symmetric monoidal category does not really enter the picture in this setting, unless you consider a postcomposition $X\colon\Gamma^\mathrm{op}\to\mathsf{Cat}\xrightarrow{N}\mathsf{sSet}$. But this is just the embedding of strict symmetric monoidal categories into $\Gamma$-spaces, which essentially are a model for $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-spaces. Here, the nerve of the original category is only the space in degree $1$ of the associated $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-space.

Thanks very much!  I need time to digest your answer.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/470808/possible-relation-between-causal-net-condensation-and-algebraic-k-theory . I am just learning algebraic K theory and Segal's famous K theory functor.   I have a question, if you have any idea, please give your comments on the question.
